# Convert data strings into Date format using ISODate function during the insertion mongo query to java code

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```
  db.collection.find().forEach(function(element){
      element.BOOKING_CREATED_DATE = ISODate(element.BOOKING_CREATED_DATE);
      db.collection.save(element);
    })
```

Please help to convert this query to DBobject type to run in spring boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongo.getDB("datarepo");

DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("rawdata");

db.eval("db.rawdata.find( { BOOKING_CREATED_DATE : { $type : 2 } } ).forEach(function(element){" +
                "element.BOOKING_CREATED_DATE = ISODate(element.BOOKING_CREATED_DATE);" +
                "db.rawdata.save(element);})")
```